# How to execute C# code behind the page if an html button is pressed?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

my current code (that doesn't do anything):

```
if (Request.Form["delete"] != null)
```

and the delete button is generated in the C# behind the page:

```
public string delete = ""; //in the public partial class

delete += " <button name=\"delete\"/>Delete</button>";
```

once I click the button - nothing happens, how can I change the `if` (or the `delete` which is the button) so that after I press the button the code will execute?

*for example:*

when I press the button, a message will appear...

```
if (Request.Form["delete"] != null)
{
Response.Write("inside the if");
}
```

**side note:**

I've tried using this code

```
Button clickedButton = sender as Button;

    if (clickedButton.ID == "delete")
```

and it didn't work as well.

Comment: https://asp.net-tutorials.com/basics/introduction/

Comment: @VDWWD what? wrong link perhaps?

Comment: First, I don't understand how the `delete` button in the string became a HTML control in the front page. But it doesn't matter that you may miss some attributes in the button `delete`: such as `runat='server' ClientIDMode='Static'` etc. After added in the HTML control, then you may have chance to get the button by `FindControlByID()` method, and attached the event handler into the button after generated. So please provide more codes about the `delete += " <button name=\"delete\"/>Delete</button>";`

Comment: @ShawnXiao simply... I just linked it in the HTML page - `<%=delete %>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (Request.Form["delete"] != null)
    {
```

and put your button in a `form`.

the `form`:

```
<form name="form_name" action="your_page.aspx" method="post" >
<input type="submit" name="delete" value="delete"/>
</form>
```

the problem? my button wasn't a `submit` button. you HAVE to use `type=submit` on it so that after it's clicked, it will actually "go to" the `form`.